# linux - filename with special character

Tags: linux, filenames

I have a directory named "--table" that i'd like to remove. I tried rmdir --table, rmdir --table and still it wouldnt work. What is the correct method ?..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
rmdir -- --table
```

The `--` in the middle signals the end of options.

The [rm man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?rm) states

```
To remove a file whose name starts with a '-', for example '-foo',  use
       one of these commands:

          rm -- -foo

          rm ./-foo
```

Although it does not state it, the double-hyphen is used by many unix commands (e.g. rmdir) to separate options from the rest of the arguments.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `--` alone to signal that what follows are file names, not switches.  So, the correct method would be `rmdir -- --table`.

Answer (score 0):

`rm -rf ./--table`

or simply, but with great care, `rm -rfi *` and answer `y` only for `--table`